# Centering Special Javascript Popup, How?

Tags: javascript, css, popup, popupwindow

I have this javascript code, lib.js. It manages my every java popup in my site. How ever it is not set to be appear absolutely centered in page, I have tried several css codes for its div. But it did not work. I also tried the famous /2 code but it didnt work or I might have added it to wrong place.

Below is my lib.js:

var currentTime = new Date();

var topP = 0;

$(document, window).keypress(function(e){

```
if (e.keyCode == 27){

    $(".yekbox").fadeOut();

    $("#yekbox_overlay").hide();

}
```

});

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$(".showme").unbind().hover(

    function(e) {

        $(".tooltip").remove();

        this.t = $(this).next(".description").html();

        $(this).append( '<div class="tooltip">' + this.t + '</div>' );

    },

    function() {

        //this.title = this.t;

        $(".tooltip").remove();

    }

).mousemove(

    function(e) {

        $(".tooltip").css({

            "top" : e.pageY + 20,

            "left" : e.pageX + 20

        });

    }

);

topP = $(this).scrollTop();

//$(".yekbox").css("top", $(window).height()-250 + "px");

//$(".yekbox").css("left", $(window).width()-(440*2) + "px");



$("#yekbox_overlay").css("height", $(window).height());

$(window, document).resize(function(){

    topP = $(this).scrollTop();

    $(".yekbox").css("marginTop", topP-250 + "px");

    if ($(window).width() > 900 ) $(".yekbox").css("left", $(window).width()-(440*2) + "px");

    $(".yekbox").css("marginLeft", "auto");

    $(".yekbox").css("marginRight", "auto");

    $("#yekbox_overlay").css("height", $(window).height());



});

$(window).scroll(function () {

    topP = $(this).scrollTop();

    $(".yekbox:visible").css("marginTop", topP-250 + "px");

    $("#yekbox_overlay:visible").css("height", $(window).height());

});

$(window).bind("scroll",function () {

    topP = $(this).scrollTop();

    $(".yekbox:visible").css("marginTop", topP-250 + "px");

    $("#yekbox_overlay:visible").css("height", $(window).height());

});

$("#yekbox_overlay").click(function(){

    $(".yekbox").fadeOut();

    $(this).hide();

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS and HTML code above doesn't help in anything.

In general, if you want a block to be centered to the parent, it should have

- A fixed width
- `margin: auto`

If you want a block absolutely centered (position absolute or fixed)

- `$('#mypopup').css('left', ($(window).width() - $('#mypopup').width()) / 2)`